# excel vb dropdownlist update

Tags: excel, vba

I an mewbie here hope somebody can help.
I have source workbook with dropdownlist in B:3 and data in B10:K50. 
Workbook2; Destination workbook is from where I need to run the code from, this is also where I have all the sheets with same name as from source wb dropdownlist.

What I like to achieve is:::work through dropdownlist is source wb, update data depanding on dropdownlist value, copy the range B10:K50, open destination workbook, find sheet name (same as from dropdownlist text) and paste data from A1.

Go back to source wb and repeat until the last value from dropdownlist. Code I am using is below BUT the problem is it's just not updating dropdownlist value in B:3:

```
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Dim Source As Range
Dim dd As DropDown
'Worksheets("Refurbs Tracker.xlsx").Select
Windows("Refurbs Tracker.xlsx").Activate
'[B3] = c.Value
'Worksheets("Refurbs Tracker.xlsx").Select
''Range("B3").Select*******************************************************************************
   Set inputRange = Evaluate(Range("B3").Validation.Formula1)
   '''***********************************************************Range("B3").Value = c.Value
For Each c In inputRange
    [B3] = c.Value
    'Range("B3").Value = c.Value
    'you might need to refresh the sheet here
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    'Copy and PasteSpecial between workbooks

  Workbooks("Refurbs Tracker.xlsx").Worksheets("Front Sheet").Range("b1:k50").Copy
  Windows("Combined.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets(c.Value).Select
  'Sheets("151 MC Paisley").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Cells.Select
  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  Range("A1").Select
  ' Begin the loop.
  'For I = 1 To WS_Count

    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Select
    'Source.Copy
    'Range("B1:K50").Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste

  'Next I
Next c
'Disable marching ants around copied range
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from your code that you tried many things. A few comments:

1. It is good practice to avoid using Activate and Select. Instead, define objects that are explicitly what you want to use. In the code below, I have defined a SourceWB (source workbook), a DestWB (destination workbook), a SourceSht (sheet with required information in SourceWB), and a DestSht (sheet in DestWB where information is deposited). In the "Initial" section of the code, you will need to change the names accordingly - I used names that fit the small problem I used to test.
2. You were trying to force the value of `B3` in the SourceSht to change. Instead of this approach, in the code below, I am finding the range of the validation list used for `B3` and using the data directly from that range.
3. In your code, you are assuming the sheet name (as defined in the validation list range) exists. I am checking that it exists, and creating the sheet if it does not.
4. You may want to consider some other actions: clearing data in the destination sheet before pasting values to it; setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the routine and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end, to avoid the flashing screen.

The code ...

```
Sub myTest()
Dim SourceWB As Workbook, DestWB As Workbook
Dim SourceSht As Worksheet, DestSht As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, myListRng As Range
Dim myListStr As String

' Initial
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks("Book1")    ' <~~ Use your Source Workbook name - "Refurbs Tracker" ?
    Set DestWB = Workbooks("Book2")      ' <~~ Use your Destination Workbook name - "Combined" ?
    Set SourceSht = SourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <~~ Use your Source Sheet name - "Front Sheet" ?

' find the drop down values
    If SourceSht.Range("B3").Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
        myListStr = Mid(SourceSht.Range("B3").Validation.Formula1, 2)
        Set myListRng = SourceWB.Names(myListStr).RefersToRange
    Else
        MsgBox "Problem with Validation List"
        Exit Sub
    End If

' loop through the drop down values and do work
    For Each c In myListRng
        If SheetExists(c.Value, DestWB) Then
            Set DestSht = DestWB.Worksheets(c.Value)
        Else
            Set DestSht = DestWB.Worksheets.Add
            DestSht.Name = c.Value
        End If
        SourceSht.Range("B10:K50").Copy
        DestSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next c
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Clean up
    Set SourceSht = Nothing
    Set DestSht = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing
    Set DestWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

... and the supporting function ...

```
Function SheetExists(Name As String, WB As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim WS As Worksheet
    SheetExists = False
    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        If Name = WS.Name Then
            SheetExists = True
            GoTo CleanUp:
        End If
    Next WS
CleanUp:
    Set WS = Nothing
End Function
```

---

**Update - based on not using a named range for validation**

The code below will work if a named range or a range reference is used for validation of Cell B3.

```
Sub myTest()
Dim SourceWB As Workbook, DestWB As Workbook
Dim SourceSht As Worksheet, DestSht As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, myListRng As Range
Dim myListStr As String, myShtStr As String, myRngStr As String

' Initial
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks("Book1")    ' <~~ Use your Source Workbook name - "Refurbs Tracker" ?
    Set DestWB = Workbooks("Book2")      ' <~~ Use your Destination Workbook name - "Combined" ?
    Set SourceSht = SourceWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <~~ Use your Source Sheet name - "Front Sheet" ?

' find the drop down values
    If SourceSht.Range("B3").Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
        myListStr = Mid(SourceSht.Range("B3").Validation.Formula1, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set myListRng = SourceWB.Names(myListStr).RefersToRange
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            myShtStr = Left(myListStr, InStr(1, myListStr, "!") - 1)
            myRngStr = Right(myListStr, Len(myListStr) - Len(myShtStr) - 1)
            myShtStr = Replace(myShtStr, "'", "")
            Set myListRng = SourceWB.Worksheets(myShtStr).Range(myRngStr)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        MsgBox "Problem with Validation List"
        Exit Sub
    End If

' loop through the drop down values and do work
    For Each c In myListRng
        If SheetExists(c.Value, DestWB) Then
            Set DestSht = DestWB.Worksheets(c.Value)
        Else
            Set DestSht = DestWB.Worksheets.Add
            DestSht.Name = c.Value
        End If
        SourceSht.Range("B10:K50").Copy
        DestSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Next c
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

' Clean up
    Set SourceSht = Nothing
    Set DestSht = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing
    Set DestWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @rizabdullah - If this answered your question, be sure to click the check mark to indicate so. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies; I am getting error message on line: Set myListRng = SourceWB.Names(myListStr).RefersToRange          RUNTIME ERROR 1004 APPLICATION DEFINED OR OBJECT DEFINED ERROR. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @rizabdullah  - what does myListStr evaluate to when you get the error?

Comment: @rizabdullah - how is the validation for cell B3 done? 1) Is it a list? 2) Is the list manually entered in the dialog? or is it a range of cells on a worksheet? 3) If it's a range of cells, is the range on the same worksheet as B3 or a different one?

Comment: Its a dropdownlist range on a different worksheeet but same workbook. Would it be easier if the list is based on same worksheet ?

Comment: Also, the new code provided works, however it is copying same data across different sheets. I think the dropdownlist is being read but not setting the value in B:3 hence not updating the data in the range. Is there anyway I could attach files here.

Comment: Just inside the loop `For Each c In myListRng` insert the line `SourceSht.Range("B3").Value = c.Value`

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. You are a star * it works. I just cant thank you enough.